# sqlalchemy wtih python ThreadPool and Flask

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, threadpool, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a database of images that need to be processed.  Each image takes around a minute to process.  I'm trying to make it multi-threaded.  I'm having trouble entering data into the database in a worker thread.  For some reason, the data isn't saved.

Here is what the code looks like.

```
images = Images.query.all()

images_ = []
for image in images:
    images_.append(image)

pool = ThreadPool()
pool.map(dostuff, (images_)) 
pool.close() 
pool.join()

def dostuff(image):
    # do stuff
    image.done = True
    db.session.commit()
```

Any ideas what could be happening? I also tried to pass the session into `dostuff(image, session)` but that didn't work either.  Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Did you add the image to session?

```
def dostuff(image):
    # do stuff
    image.done = True
    db.session.add(image)
    db.session.commit()
```